# :NEW table or view doesn't exist

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-insert

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to create this trigger on SQLdeveloper, and I'm getting "table or view does not exist" and can't solve it. Why is this not working? Thanks in advance!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insertion
    AFTER 
    INSERT
    ON FUNC
FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN
    select * from :NEW;
END;
```

Comment: `:NEW` doesn't stand for a table. Also, `select` requires an `into` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can't select from `:NEW` - besides, running a `SELECT` query like so in a trigger does not make really sense.

You *can*, however, use `:NEW` to access all values of the row being inserted, and use them for whatever your purpose is. You can also modify them, if you have `before` trigger.

Here is an example that copies the row being inserted to another table, with a few changes to the original values:

```
create table func(id int, val varchar(10));
create table bck (id int, val varchar(10));

create or replace trigger trg_func_after_insert
    after insert on func 
    for each row   
begin
    insert into bck (id, val) values (:new.id + 1, :new.val || '_bck');
end;
/
```

Now say a new row is inserted to `func`:

```
insert into func (id, val) values (1, 'foo');
```

The content ìs copied to `bck`:

```
select * from bck;

ID | VAL    
-: | :------
 2 | foo_bck
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=906a05d6d4e99e320c819e9b50356c20)**

Comment: I have an assignment that I tells me to after every insertion on the func table, show what has been inserted. I couldn't think of something other than the select on trigger

Comment: @placementw: I don't know what you mean by *show*. Maybe you want `dbms_output.put_line()` to print the values to PL/SQL output (note that not all clients are able to read that output though).